# Clutter Performance Issue with 965gm GPU

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, 20.04, opengl, clutter

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and when I look my system details my gpu is named as Intel® 965GM but if I install Ubuntu 20.04 it is named as Intel® 965GM (CL). System ui and google chrome is really smooth with drivers of 16.04 but not with 20.04. I tried to install unity desktop to 20.04 but again chrome is not as smooth as 16.04. What is the difference between these two version of drivers? If I figure it out I can finally upgrade to 20.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /etc/environment file with nano or gedit and add;

CLUTTER_DRIVER=gles2

Save files than reboot your machine.

Gnome UI will be silky smooth even with GMA965, but I could not be able to get smoothness for firefox. But it is enough for now.